# How do I isolate a double exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to isolate $x$ in the equation $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{4n}\right)^{2^{x-1}-1}$

Right now I have $2\sqrt{n}\epsilon = \left(\frac{1}{4n}\right)^{2^{x-1}-1}$, but I'm having trouble seeing how I can use log properties here.

Thank you for the help.

EDIT: I got $x = \frac{\left(log(\frac{log\left(2\sqrt{n}\epsilon\right)}{log\left(\frac{1}{4n}\right)} + 1\right)}{log2} + 1$. Is this correct? It looks messy.

Comment: Take it one step at a time.  What do you get when you take the log of both sides?

Comment: This is $\epsilon = (1/4n)^{2^{x-1}-1/2}$.

Comment: Check whether you really need an exact solution. If this is a limit proof, for example, you might only need $\geq$, not $=$.

Comment: Yes, I need an exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Take the log of both sides. Then recall that $\log(a^b) = b \log(a)$. You may have to do this more than once...

Comment: I got $x = log\left(log\left(2\sqrt{n}\epsilon - \frac{1}{4n}\right) - 1\right) + 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I see an error in my work. I'll fix it now.